# Range of $f(x) = \ln(\arctan(e^x − 2015))$ without derivatives

Tags: calculus, functions

$$f(x) = \ln(\arctan(e^x − 2015))$$

I know how to find the range of this function by getting the minimum and maximum from the derivative, but is there another way of doing it without calculus?

Comment: The arctangent function is bounded in absolute value by $\pi/2$.  Therefore, the range is $(-\infty,\log (\pi/2))$.

Comment: @SujithZis The log is undefined for $x<0$ for real variables.

Comment: @Dr.MV why wouldn't it be (ln(-pi/2) , ln(pi/2)) ?

Comment: The problem is ill-posed unless the region for $x$ is given.

Comment: No.  The log function is not defined for negatve arguments, for real-valued functions.  The domain is therefore restricted to be $x>\log 2015$.  And the range is $(-\infty,\log \pi/2)$.

Answer (score 2):

How about this :

$e^x-2015$ is strictly increasing and continuous
$\arctan(x)$ is strictly increasing and continuous
$\ln(x)$ is strictly increasing and continuous

So $f$ is stricly increasing and continuous.

Then it's not hard to see that $f$ is defined on $]\ln(2015),+\infty[$, hence the range will be

$$\left]\lim_{x\to \ln(2015)} f(x), \lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x) \right[ = \left]-\infty,\ln\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right[$$

Comment: That cannot be correct.  The arctangent is bounded in absolute value by $\pi/2$.

Comment: @Dr.MV : you're totally right, the limit is indeed $\ln(\pi/2)$